# Charger works on Computers but not in the car?

Tags: ipod-touch, charging

I bought a [new charging cable](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/8==D/3448752.p?id=1218402858045&skuId=3448752) for my iPod the other day. I used it to plug my iPod into my laptop and it works just fine. However, I plugged it into the radio transmitter in my car (which is itself plugged into the cigarette lighter for power) and the EL lighting keeps flashing on and off, meaning it is repeatedly getting then losing power. My original cable did work and stayed on but that broke which is why I bought the new one.

Is the cigarette lighter not a reliable source of power for this new cable?

Comment: The cable is flashing but is the device switching from a charging state to a non-charging state?

Comment: Yes it is. On my iPod, the battery with the black background will come up then disappear about once-twice a second.